# Windows phone draw rectangle

Tags: windows-phone, image

I am just want to draw a rectangle in windows phone canvas. I have tried some technique but each time i have failed to accomplish my job. i want to draw this rectangle and use just like in the paint application of the windows in desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

There are two examples for you, you can download it from the below links.

[Sample Project 1](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-2-drawing-shapes-with-finger)

[Sample Project](http://fingerpaint.codeplex.com/)